# What is the package for URLLoader and URLRequest in Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

I am trying to setup two variables:

```
var xmlURLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
```

I am taking some old AS code and trying to plug it into Flash Builder. I am getting a "Type not found." warning with those variable declarations. Does anyone know which package to import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
flash.net.URLLoader;
flash.net.URLRequest;
```

[Bookmark me](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package-detail.html).